# Android: recyclerview How to implemente setMultiChoiceListener?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and I want to implement a setMultiChoiceListener.
Why is there no such function in the recyclerview?

I do not want a simple longclick because the longclick executes the method only when the finger is no longer on the screen, while the set multichoice it performs the function after 1 second even if the finger is still on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no multi choice listener because the RecylerView is designed that way , it recycles the layout items that are no longer visible and recreates them when needed.

As a workaround you could do the following :

```
1.include a radio button that shows the
  selected state in the recyclerview item when clicked
2.In the adapter have an list of your choosing (eg. ArrayList) 
  that contains your selected objects (add/remove them when selected/deselected)
3.In the adapter you can make a method (eg. getSelectedItems()) that will 
  return that list.
```

If you provide what have you tried so far I will help you with the code

Comment: This works without the radio buttons as well , you can implement another behavior that shows the user that the item is selected (let's say colour in a different color the item ) . The idea is that you have a list in the adapter in which you will store all the selected items as per user selection